# how to lighten only the lines you need using a stream

Tags: filter, stream

This is my text

```
"Marek, Kowalski; 10000.00 zł; umowa o pracę
Kowalska, Ania B.; 10011.00 zł; zlecenie
Nowak, Jan, 9321.00 zł; zlecenie
Nowak, Janina, 9322.00 zł; zlecenie
Pierzak, Jan, 9321.00 zł; zlecenie 
eksport danych
Pietrzak, Janina, 9322.00 zł; zlecenie
Woźniak, Marek, ; zlecenie"
```

I have to highlight 3 lines with a description of the employee, if his surname does not have a "Kowalsk" root, in descending order of salary, that is, lines number 3, 4 and 5

```
String fileName = "earnings.txt";
        try (Stream<String> strings = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
                   strings.filter(o -> !o.contains("Kowalsk"))
                    .filter(o -> o.contains("zł"))
                    .limit(3).forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Welcome.  What have you tried so far?  Please share whatever code you have.

Comment: Highlight in what exactly? And this question seems to have nothing to do with the tag you added. Did you read that tag's description? Please remember when posting here that we have zero information available to us other than what you provide in your question. We can't see your screen or read your mind, and we don't know what you're trying to do unless you tell us.